# CListCtrl::GetItemNext returns start item

Tags: mfc, windows-mobile, clistctrl

I have a CListCtrl object in my C++ MFC app for Windows Mobile 6. When I call listctrl.GetNextItem(0, LVNI_ABOVE) I should therefore get back -1 (no item above first item), but if (and only if) the list has exactly one item, the call returns 0, even though MSDN says "The specified item itself is excluded from the search". Is this a known bug?

Answer (score 1):

You can search for bugs here:
https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/Feedback